# How can I create a yum repository from downloaded packages?

Tags: yum

How can one setup local yum repository using the downloaded rpm packages?

This is a note to self. I am not sure if this good way, but I am trying nevertheless.

Comment: I completely understand the negative vote. However I wanted this note for my own reference. I could not find any better way to do this on meta exchange as well. Suggestions to take note for self are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest searching first. This question has been asked and answered here several times.

Answer (score 2):

Details are [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-use-yum-repositories-on-a-centos-6-vps)

In summary:

- yum install createrepo
- mkdir /repository1
- copy packages to /repository1
- createrepo /repository1
- Create yum.repo file

  > [customrepo]
  >   name=Custom Repository
  >   baseurl=file:///repository1/
  >   enabled=1
  >   gpgcheck=0

Comment: Setting `gpgcheck=1` is Strongly recommended