# Create local yum repository for a package which is available on http

Tags: centos, centos7, yum

I am trying to create local yum repo for packages.
I have followed steps here to create the repo: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/create-local-yum-repository-centos

But now, I want to create repo for a package helix-swarm which is available here: http://package.perforce.com/yum/rhel/7/x86_64/

Based on the answer here [How can I create a yum repository from downloaded packages?](https://serverfault.com/questions/619751/how-can-i-create-a-yum-repository-from-downloaded-packages) , it seems I can do it by downloading the rpm packages and run `createrepo` command. But is there a simpler way to do this? As you can see, this link has more than 40 rpm packages and downloading it one by one and creating repo is tedious task. So wondering if there is an easy way to create the local repo.

Pardon me if its too novice questions to ask on this platform.

Comment: reposync may do what you want

Comment: That web URL already contains a valid yum repo.  Why are you not [using it directly](https://www.perforce.com/perforce-packages) or just mirroring it?

Comment: @MichaelHampton the server doesn't have access to external URL and also can't mirror it. Hence I am trying to create my own internal repo which can be used.

Comment: Exactly! That's why you should just mirror it.

Comment: thanks @MichaelHampton it helped. can you please help how we can mirror or make local copy of packages like php-pecl https://pecl.php.net/. i see this tutorial but that doesn't seems to help: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/install-php-redis-on-centos-8-rhel-8-linux/